# React Autocomplete Material UI - Textfield with id value

Tags: reactjs

I have a React form with Autocomplete Material UI.

I'm using useState for save selected_problem_id with onChange,

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const TabLead = ({ lead, sources, lead_problems }) => {

  const [selectedProblemId, setSelectedProblemId] = useState(lead.problem_id); 

  return (
    <div className="row">
        <Autocomplete 
        id="problem_id"  
        options={lead_problems}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
        defaultValue={lead.lead_problems ? lead.lead_problems.problem : null}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === selectedProblemId}
        onChange={(event, option) => {  
          if (option?.id) {
            setSelectedProblemId(option.id);
          } else {
            setSelectedProblemId("");
          }
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField  margin="normal" {...params} label="Problem" />} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default TabLead
```

This is rendered input, value with label

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="problem_id" type="text" role="combobox" value="Need a Doctor">
```

I would like to get value with id

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="problem_id" type="text" role="combobox" value="1">
```

is there a way for get a input value different from label?

Comment: `input` value is what user see on a screen. For the backend use `selected_problem.id`.

Comment: @user4980215 where? if I use 'selected_problem.id' on getOptionLabel, user will see id and not label.
I need something like this: 
<TextField  value={selected_problem} margin="normal" {...params} label="Problem" />} />

Comment: How do you save to backend?

Comment: @user4980215 I retrieve all values input including this with: e.target.elements.problem_id.value and send it through an Axios api callback

Comment: This not how you do forms in react. Usually you follow the controlled or uncontrolled input pattern. In this case you can add `onChange` prop and call it when new option is selected: `onChange(option)`. The parent component updates the form data accordingly.

Comment: @user4980215 Yes I'm new to react, the dynamics are very different. I solved it thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple, but I'm new to React, it's very different from the classic html.

I solved passing the entire 'option' object after onChange.

```
<Autocomplete 
    id="problem_id"  
    options={leadProblems}
    defaultValue={lead.lead_problems ? lead.lead_problems.problem : null}
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === selectedProblem.id}
    onChange={(event, option) => {  
      if (option?.id) {
        setSelectedProblem(option);
      } else {
        setSelectedProblem("");
      }
    }}
    renderInput={(params) =>
```

Then retrieving the id

```
const problem_id = selectedProblem.id;
```